# How to read STDOUT from another app in Java without buffering

Tags: java, windows

From Java, I run a C++ app which logs its progress as it proceeds, and want to monitor that there is some progress continually, so (in Java) I monitor process.getInputStream() and process.getErrorStream().  When I run the C++ app from the command line, the log appears one line at a time as it progresses (about 1 line very 1-2 seconds).  From the Java monitor, I'm not getting the data in realtime, and am not sure who is buffering it.

I can look at the C++ code (though it's rather complex) and try to put flush() calls as necessary, but the data appears in realtime when I run it from cmd.exe, so before I do that, I'd like to check out if there is something else along the way that I have to do.  Is there something in Java I have to do to get the data in realtime, to make sure the input stream is not buffered?

I'm running in Windows XP and above.

I tried

```
            for (;;) {
                int c = is.read();
                if (c < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print(c);
                System.out.flush();
            }
            if (true) {
                return;
            }
```

and also tried

```
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                synchronized (lastActivityTime) {
                    lastActivityTime = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                }
                if (pw != null) {
                    pw.println(type + line);
                    pw.flush();
                }
            }
```

Comment: you should post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the source process that is doing the buffering, in the `stdio` library. There is nothing you can do about that at the Java end. You have to put `fflush()` calls into the C++ code, or put up with it and wait. The data appears in real time when you run from cmd.exe because stdio behaves differently when attached to what it thinks is a real terminal.

Comment: I put _fflushall() calls in the main app, it works correctly now.  I wasn't sure if there was something I could do on Java's side.  Thanks.

Comment: I just learned about "Accepting answers", and am going back to old posts and doing it.  Sorry for the late acknowledgements!